# Hatcher 3.2.17 cohomology ring of James reduced product of a sphere

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, exterior-algebra

the goal of this exercise is (after getting inspired by Hatcher's proof in the even dimensional case (prop 3.22)) to compute
$$H^*(J(S^n), \mathbb{Z}), n=2k+1$$
And we are told that this should be $\bigwedge[\alpha]\otimes \Gamma[\beta]$ (all of these over $\mathbb{Z}$) with $|\alpha|=n, |\beta|=2n$.

I know this can be done material from chapter 3.C, computing instead the ponytragin product, and then dualising. I was able to use this method, I would like help with the expected direct method.

So far I have successfully gotten the abelian group structure, that is a copy of $\mathbb{Z}$ in each dimension a multiple of $n$ (Hatcher does this for all $n$ in his proof of Prop 3.22), and if we denote $\alpha$ a generator of $H^n$, then $\alpha$ generates a subalgebra of the form $\bigwedge[\alpha]$.

Let's denote $\beta$ a generator of $H^{2n}$ and $q_m: (S^n)^m\to J_m(S^n)$ the quotient map on which this proof relies on. The other very useful fact we have is that we can understand $H^i(J(S^n))$ using $H^i(J_m(S^n))$ whenever $i\leq m$ using that the inclusion induces an isomorphism.

To understand $\beta^k$ we work in $J_{2k}(S^n)$ and to understand $\alpha\beta^{k}$ we work in $J_{2k+1}(S^n)$ using that $q_m$ induces an isomorphism on $H^{nm}(J_m(S^n))$. In order to succesfully imitate the proof of Hatcher I need to understand $q^*_m(\beta)$ and this is where I am lost.

If we write $H^*((S^n)^m)=\bigwedge[x_1, ..., x_m], |x_i|=n$, my intution wants to say $q_m^*(\beta)=\sum_{(i,j)} x_ix_j$, but I think this is equal to $0$, which isn't what it should be. Hence my need for help. 
.

Thanks a lot for your help. Sorry if my question is a bit too rambly

Comment: I just realized that you might be using an older version. The proof of this part is actually covered in the (latest version?) of the book which can be found on his website.

Comment: Note that $q^*(\beta)=\sum_{i<j}x_ix_j$ which is non-zero, as each cohomology class in this sum comes from the dual of a $2n$-cell.

Comment: @Kevin.S mmmh, I'll go check it out then. Oh I think I took into account some ordering on the cells of a product of CW complexes which doesn't actually exist, hence the difference in computation of $q^*(\beta)$. Thanks